Error C2794 "iterator_category": not a member of any direct or indirect base class of "std::iterator_traits<_InIt>"
here is my code:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class StrReader {
public:
    class iterator {
    public:
        typedef size_t  difference_type;
        typedef char value_type;
        typedef value_type* pointer_type;
        typedef value_type& reference;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

        explicit iterator(char* stream)
            :value(*stream)
            ,pos(stream)
        {}

        reference operator*()
        {
            return value;
        }

        pointer_type operator->()
        {
            return &value;
        }

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            pos += 1;
            value = *pos;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            iterator temp(*this);
            ++*this;
            return temp;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const 
        {
            return (value == rhs.value && pos == rhs.pos);
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const
        {
            return (value != rhs.value && pos != rhs.pos);
        }

    private:
        value_type value;
        char* pos;
    };

    explicit StrReader(char* input)
        :str(input)
    {}

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(str);
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(str+strlen(str));
    }

private:
    char* str;
};

int main()
{
    char* str = new char[1024]();
    strcpy(str, "Hello World +1");
    StrReader reader(str);
    std::transform(reader.begin(), reader.end(), reader.begin(), toupper);
    return 0;
}

Error when compiling code：
Error C2794 "iterator_category": not a member of any direct or indirect base class of "std::iterator_traits<_InIt>".
 with
 [
 _InIt=StrReader::iterator
 ] charArray D:\Program Files\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xutility 1076     

I don't know what's wrong in the code, I just want to implement an iterator for traversing an array of characters, but I don't want to use the C++ STL container.

What happens if you add the missing header files? #include <cstring> #include <iterator>

After adding these header files, the same error persists.

Odd, it compiles file for me both in godbolt.org and in my local Visual Studio 2022 installation.

It also compiles for me in MSVC 2022, with C++20. Which version of C++ do you use @DevinPotter ?

I am using C++ 11 version @wohlstad

@DevinPotter sounds like you use a very old IDE and C++ version. Can't you upgrade ?

As a side note, after adding the cstring header, it compiles fine on g++.

I'm sorry, I just answered wrong. I'm using C++14 version. The compiler is MSVC 2022. @wohlstad

@DevinPotter any reason not to use C++20 (it's a simple change in project settings) ?

The company is using visual studio 2015, using the C++ 11 standard. @wohlstad

Thanks for the heads up. I'll try it with the gcc compiler. I don't know if the C++11 standard will compile. @ChristianStieber

You are also missing #include <cctype> and
#include <cstdint>. gcc and clang both compile the code in C++11 mode. If you plan on upgrading to C++20 some time, don't take the address of standard library functions (like toupper) unless they are listed as designated addressable functions. toupper is not one of them.

@TedLyngmo only because their implementations of std::transform don't use iterator_traits https://godbolt.org/z/94bnG9qsT

typedef value_type* pointer_type;

should be
typedef value_type* pointer;

Before c++ 20 if any of the iterator typedefs were missing then std::iterator_traits is an empty class. After c++20 pointer is optional so that's why upgrading to c++20 allows your code to compile
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits

Lol, can't believe I missed that one :-)

@TedLyngmo took a lot of staring at it for me to find it too

@AlanBirtles good spot ! +1
